# How do I globally enable "strict" handling of LocalDate values using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

Jackson [Java 8 Date/time module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) issue [jackson-modules-java8#212](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/212) mentions enabling "strict" handling via a global default:

> Currently `LocalDateDeserializer` automatically accepts non-standard format where time part also exists.
> While this is useful for some use cases, compatibility, it seems reasonable that if user forces "strict" handling (via `@JsonFormat`, or global default), that part would not be accepted.

However, I am completely failing at figuring out how to enable this globally.  I've checked configuration classes such as [`DeserializationFeature`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) and done Internet & Stack Overflow searches for this, but have not come up with an answer.

How can I enable "strict" handling of `LocalDate`, such that `@JsonFormat` behaves the same as `@JsonFormat(lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)` for values deserialized by Jackson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set global leniency by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#setDefaultLeniency`.

But this won't fail when `LocalDate` contains the time part too. Since there is strange logic in `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer`. It uses `DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_TIME` as default formatter, which doesn't allow time part, but when deserializer parses datetime, this code runs:

```java
try {
    // as per [datatype-jsr310#37], only check for optional (and, incorrect...) time marker 'T'
    // if we are using default formatter
    DateTimeFormatter format = _formatter;
    if (format == DEFAULT_FORMATTER) {
        // JavaScript by default includes time in JSON serialized Dates (UTC/ISO instant format).
        if (string.length() > 10 && string.charAt(10) == 'T') {
           if (string.endsWith("Z")) {
               return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(string), ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
           } else {
               return LocalDate.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
           }
        }
    }
    return LocalDate.parse(string, format);
} catch (DateTimeException e) {
    return _handleDateTimeException(ctxt, e, string);
}
```

You can avoid this by duplicating default `DateTimeFormatter`. Here is my proposal for this:

```java
class ObjectMapperPlayground {

    @Data
    static class Test {
        LocalDate date;
    }

    private static DateTimeFormatter clone(DateTimeFormatter dtf) {
        ResolverStyle oldStyle = dtf.getResolverStyle();
        ResolverStyle newStyle = Arrays.stream(ResolverStyle.values())
                .filter(Predicate.not(Predicate.isEqual(oldStyle)))
                .findAny()
                // should never happen
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("ResolverStyle enum has single value."));
        // DateTimeFormatter has a check which makes our life a little harder :)
        /*
            public DateTimeFormatter withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle resolverStyle) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(resolverStyle, "resolverStyle");
                if (Objects.equals(this.resolverStyle, resolverStyle)) {
                    return this;
                }
                return new DateTimeFormatter(printerParser, locale, decimalStyle, resolverStyle, resolverFields, chrono, zone);
            }
         */
        return dtf.withResolverStyle(newStyle).withResolverStyle(oldStyle);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper regularMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                // no clone here
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule().addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)))
                .setDefaultLeniency(false);

        // OK
        regularMapper.readValue("{\"date\":\"2021-01-01T12:12:12\"}", Test.class);

        ObjectMapper dupMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                // with clone
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule().addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(clone(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE))))
                .setDefaultLeniency(false);

        // throws
        dupMapper.readValue("{\"date\":\"2021-01-01T12:12:12\"}", Test.class);
    }
}
```

### Jackson databind 2.13

As for version 2.13 of `JavaTime` module, lenient check was added for disallowing time part in `LocalDate`. So workaround with a copy of `DateTimeFormatter` is not needed, `setDefaultLeniency(false)` should be enough.

Comment: It will start working with respect to rejecting a time part once 2.13 is released, due to the changes introduced in the linked issue fix ([jackson-modules-java8#212](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/212)).

Comment: `setDefaultLeniency` is exactly what I was failing to find. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I've edited my answer for 2.13 case

Comment: When using the newer builder approach to constructing an `ObjectMapper`, the builder has an analogous [defaultLeniency()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.html#defaultLeniency-java.lang.Boolean-) method: `JsonMapper.builder().defaultLeniency(true).build()`